# Incomplete SVF2 Files using Autodesk Platform Services Model Derivative API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm trying to convert some rather complex Autodesk Inventor models to SVF2 using the APS Model Derivative API. Some models convert without issue but most are missing some or all components. In some cases when attempting to view the model I am just presented with the following dialog:

[image: "Model is Empty" dialog]

Given that some models convert just fine but others have problems, I think it's an issue with the data rather than problems in how I'm submitting the jobs, but I can't be sure. The jobs always return a result of success even when the models are completely empty.

I can take some files that are not visible in a given assembly and add them to another assembly, and they are visible in the SVF2 in the new assembly, so I don't think it's related to their geometry.

Is there some additional job output I can request to see where and why the failure is happening?

[EDIT]: I am using PowerShell for file upload and job submission

Here is the script I'm using for upload and SVF2 creation:

```
$clientID = "[REDACTED]"
$clientSecret = "[REDACTED]"
$bucketName = "[REDACTED]"
$zipFile = "C:\Work\FileName.zip"
$topAssemblyName = "FileName.iam"

#get access token
function Authenticate-Forge()
{
    $form = @{
        client_id = $clientID
        client_secret = $clientSecret
        grant_type = 'client_credentials'
        scope = 'data:write data:read bucket:create bucket:delete'
    }
    
    $uri = 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate'
    
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Body $form -Method Post
    
    return $result.access_token
}

$token = Authenticate-Forge


#create a bucket for storing files
$bucketsURI = 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets'

$bodyHash = @{
    bucketKey = $bucketName
    access = 'full'
    policyKey = 'persistent'

}

$bucketHeaders = @{
    'Authorization' = "Bearer $($token)"
    'Content-Type' = "application/json"
}

$bodyJSON = ConvertTo-Json $bodyHash

$bucketResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $bucketsURI -Headers $bucketHeaders -Method Post -Body $bodyJSON

#Get a signed URL for upload
$filekey = [IO.Path]::GetFileName($zipFile).Replace(" ", "_")
$signedUploadURI = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/$($bucketName)/objects/$($filekey)/signeds3upload?minutesExpiration=20"

$signedUploadHeaders = @{
    'Authorization' = "Bearer $($token)"
    'Accept-Encoding' = "gzip, deflate"
}


#Get a signed URL for upload
$signedURLResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $signedUploadURI -Headers $signedUploadHeaders

$uploadKey = $signedURLResponse.uploadKey
$contentUploadSignedURL = $signedURLResponse.urls[0]

#Upload the file
$uploadHeaders = @{
    'Accept-Encoding' = "gzip, deflate"
}


$uploadResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $contentUploadSignedURL -Headers $uploadHeaders -InFile $zipFile

#finalize the upload
$finalizeUploadURI = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/$($bucketName)/objects/$($filekey)/signeds3upload"
$finalizeUploadHeaders = @{
    'Authorization' = "Bearer $($token)"
    'Accept-Encoding' = "gzip, deflate"
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
}

$finalizebodyHash = @{
    uploadKey = $uploadKey
}
$finalizebodyJSON = ConvertTo-Json $finalizebodyHash

$finalizeUploadResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $finalizeUploadURI -Headers $finalizeUploadHeaders -Body $finalizebodyJSON

$sourceFileObjectKey = $finalizeUploadResponse.objectKey
$sourceFileURN = $finalizeUploadResponse.objectId

$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($sourceFileURN)
$encodedURN = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$encodedURNSafe = $encodedURN.TrimEnd("=").Replace("+","-").Replace("/","_")

#Convert to SVF
$convertHeaders = @{
    'Authorization' = "Bearer $($token)"
    'Content-Type' = "application/json"
    'x-ads-force' = "true"
}

$convertURI = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job"

$convSVFBodyHash = @{
    'input' = @{
        'urn' = $encodedURNSafe
        'rootFilename' = $topAssemblyName
        'compressedUrn' = $true
    }
    'output' = @{
        'destination' = @{
            'region' = 'us'
        }
        'formats' = @(
            @{
                'type' = 'svf2'
                'views' = @('3d')
            }
        )
    }
}

$convSVFBodyJSON = ConvertTo-Json $convSVFBodyHash -Depth 4
$convertResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $convertURI -Headers $convertHeaders -Body $convSVFBodyJSON
$convertResponse

#check the status of the job
$statusURI = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/$($encodedURNSafe)/manifest"
$statusHeaders = @{'Authorization' = "Bearer $($token)"}
$statusResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $statusURI -Headers $statusHeaders
$statusResponse
```

I have tried everything short of completely rebuilding the assemblies. I have made sure that all files are migrated to the same release of Inventor, eliminated modeling errors, etc. The assemblies open fine in Inventor with no issues, all files migrated, etc.

Comment: Not sure if in the meantime you contacted us through email as well where you provided samples models that can be used to reproduce the issue - but if not, then please do. One thing that comes to mind is that MD only translates the active LOD/Model State and active Design View - so if that happens to be empty for some reason then you'd end up with an empty model.